# Fonts in Google Earth look bad even after installing Microsoft Fonts

Tags: fonts, google-earth

Google Earth fonts look bad, even after installing the Microsoft font package.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change global font settings.

Download and install MyUnity from Ubuntu Software Center.

Launch it and click on the Fonts section. Here you can edit fonts.

Comment: didn't influence the GE fonts