# Why do fonts look bad in some applications?

Tags: windows, xubuntu, fonts, eclipse

My `Eclipse IDE` looks horrible ever since I installed  Xubuntu.

[image]

This question was never answered, but it's exactly what I have trouble with:
[Fonts look bad in Microsoft Office using Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134542/fonts-look-bad-in-microsoft-office-using-wine)

My eclipse font is also a windows font `Consolas`. I'm really used to it, and I'd love to get it back.

EDIT: Here's another unanswered question related to windows fonts: [Fonts in Google Earth look bad even after installing Microsoft Fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153508/fonts-in-google-earth-look-bad-even-after-installing-microsoft-fonts?rq=1).

Comment: Have you installed `xubuntu-restricted-extras`? You will need to first enable `multiverse` in your Software Sources. That will install a lot of Microsoft fonts for you.

Comment: How did you install `Consolas`? You may want to install it manually by copying the relevant files from a Windows installation.

Comment: I've installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, and yes, I've installed `Consolas` manually. Expand on relevant files; there's only one file you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you a fully qualified answer here but some hints:

- Windows core fonts are heavily optimized for Windows. They look slightly off everywhere else.
- The width of boldface and regular is different in most fixed-width fonts. Reconfigure your eclipse appearance settings so that no boldface is used or try 'ubuntu mono' which just works.
- Droid Sans Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono are also viable alternatives to the Sans Mono default.
- The [Inconsolata](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) font tries to reach the Consolas experience under Linux.

Comment: The best answer I've found yet! Why doesn't Inconsolata have a `normal` style? It only allows `italics`, `medium` and others. The medium seems to be doing it. I guess it's just the nomenclature?

Comment: `medium` is slightly bolder than `normal`. Perhaps the font author thought that `normal` would be too thin.